# Spatial Reference Conversion

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps

I am currently having some problem with the spatial reference projection on the map in Android.

Basically I have a base map which is OneMap and all the coordinates stored in database is in SVY21 format. However, I wanted to display it using GoogleMap which is in WGS84 format. I wonder is there any ways for me to convert it in Java?

Because by using [OneMap Api Documentation](http://www.onemap.sg/api/help/), it has a conversion method which is in JavaScript. However, I need it to be in Java for my Android project. Any ideas?

Comment: Down voter mind to explain? And why should it closed? It's technically related :(

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript-method requests a REST-service, you may do the same.

Documentation: http://www.onemap.sg/api/help/Geometry.aspx (what you are looking for is "Project")

Comment: I see. But is there anyway to just convert the coordinates itself without projecting them onto the map?

Comment: The service simply returns the converted coordinates and didn't project them on a map.